# PICKCHARS doesn't work in KeePass

Tags: keepass

I use:

- KeePass 1.27 portable version
- Windows 7
- Opera 12.10.

I added a new entry, in `Notes` field I put in below command:

```
Auto-Type: {TAB}{USERNAME}{TAB}{PICKCHARS:Password:C=5}{ENTER}
```

I use this entry this way:

- Left mouse button on entry
- select `Open URL(s)` function
- select `Perform Auto-Type` function

after above sequence `KeePass` behaves as below

- open the page with user name filed
- go to user name filed
- fill user name
- open the page with password filed

The page with password contains filed for every char from the password. I need fill only some of them, for example 1st, 3rd,5th,7th,8th.

After the described sequence I'm expecting a dialog box:
[image]

but the window doesn't open. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://keepass.info/help/base/placeholders.html) it works only for 2.x version.